Can we use redux with react-web component and AEM components at the same time
I am trying to use redux in my AEM project for the UI part.
I have the below folder structure
- all
- core
- dispatcher
- ui.apps
- ui.frontend
    - dist
    - node_modules
    - src
      - app
        - component
        - site
          - utilities
            - store.js
    - package.json
- ui.frontend.react
  - build
  - node_modules
  - public
    - index.html
  - src
    - components
      - custom-button
- etc...

I my ui.frontend folder I have the redux toolkit package, and I have created a store as following
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

function countReducer(state = initialState, action) {
const counter = state.count;
    if (action.type === 'INCREMENT') {
      return {
        ...state, 
        count: counter + 1
    };
    }else if (action.type === 'DECREMENT'){
      return {...state, count: counter-1};
    }else{
      return state;
    }
}

const store = configureStore({reducer: {
    count: countReducer
}});

export default store;    

I am able to increment and decrement the count using the components inside ui.frontend folder.
How do I use the same store, for react-web components that are built inside ui.frontend.react folder
<custom-button text="Custom Button 1"></custom-button>

custom-button is a react web component inside ui.frontend.react
import React from "react";
import {
  byAttrVal,
  createCustomElement,
  DOMModel,
  // @ts-ignore
} from "@adobe/react-webcomponent";
import "./index.scss";
import store from "../../../../ui.frontend/src/app/site/utilities/store";

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ text }) => {

  const onClick = (event: any) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
  };
...
...

const CustomButton = createCustomElement(Button, ButtonModel, "element");

customElements.define("custom-button", CustomButton);

This is giving an error as the store.js file is outside src folder,
Please note, for local development, ui.frontend folder uses port 8000 and ui.frontend.react uses port 3000. For production, the js will be compiled and load as script and react-web-component will be authored like other AEM components
Any help would be appreciated

It's not recommended to import the store directly like this, there are other ways to access the store. Are you rendering a Redux Provider component component in your UI anywhere?

@DrewReese - currently I am not using Redux Provider, I am not sure if Redux Provider can be used in this situation

Ok, well if you are using React, and that is working, then you can use and render the React-Redux Provider component around the rendered ReactTree and pass it the global store instance. Redux is Javascript/Typescript, so it can be used anywhere where JS/TS is used. Where is the store being created and where else are you trying to use it? I think we need more details and context what you are trying to do overall.

@DrewReese - I am creating the store inside ui.frontend/src/app/site/utilities folder
I need to access the store in my custom-button component inside ui.frontend.react folder. Updated info in the description

@DrewReese - unlike the straight forward implementation of Redux in react, I am trying to create the store in my vanilla js and then have the react web component access it. The store is not being created within the react context
